# VisualVM - Cannot take heap dump

Tags: java, visualvm

When I click on the Heap Dump button in VisualVM 1.3.8, I get the following error:

> Cannot take heap dump for user@localhost:9090

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

**Edit #1**

Environment is:

- RHEL6
- Tomcat 7.0.68
- Java 1.7.0_45

Options are:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true\
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/file_to_pwd \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/file_to_access \
-Xms1256m \
-Xmx1256m \
-XX:PermSize=768m \
-XX:MaxPermSize=768m \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-server"
```

**Edit #2**

Here is the listener for JMX.

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="9090" rmiServerPortPlatform="9091" />
```

Comment: Please provide some details of the environment.

Comment: Added details for the environment

Comment: `jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true` should show some details of the error on the console.

Comment: I'm using VisualVM binary on Windows. Does this still apply?

Comment: I am sure it applies :)

Comment: Added it to etc/visualvm.conf... looking for the "console"...

Comment: Are you monitoring local or remote application?

Comment: I am monitoring a remote server containing many applications

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. We had JDK 1.8 also present on the server.

```
cd /path/to/java/jdk1.8.0_65/
./jmap -dump:format=b,file=/path/to/dump/tomcat_dump.bin PID
```

Open `/path/to/dump/tomcat_dump.bin` using `VisualVM` (I had to use Filezilla to bring it to my workstation).

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is permission issue. In Windows right click on the jvisualvm executable and run as administrator solves this issue.